# Is it possible to execute post exit criteria action in Marketing Cloud Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, action

I am using Salesforce data as an Entry Audience of the journey in Marketing Cloud. I have defined exit criteria in the journey to remove the subscriber from the journey after the value of a checkbox changes in Salescloud.

What I would like to do is to change another object record in Salescloud **after** the entry audience record exits the journey.

Is it possible to define a post-exit criteria action somewhere in Marketing Cloud journey settings, or do I have to write a trigger/define workflow in Salescloud to update the second record after my first record checkbox value changes?

Comment: Hi @andrej, I don't see any easy way to do this in Marketing cloud. As you said the easiest and the best way is to write a trigger/define workflow in Salescloud

Comment: Hi @andrej, I faced the same issue recently.  This would make for a great feature enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

Once a customer exits the journey there isn't any journey builder activity to trigger an action. As Praveen said the best way would be to trigger something in Salescloud that looks at if a contact has entered the journey and met the goal criteria since.